# Interview puzzle with a deck of cards, some cards upside-down

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

You are sitting in a dark room. It is completely dark. You can't see anything and there is no way that you can make light. Basically, just assume that you are blind for this task.

There is a table in front of you and you feel a deck of cards in your hand. Now the deck is shuffled. But not only shuffled, 18 cards out of the 53 are right-side up and the rest are upside down.

Your task is to separate the deck into 2 piles, which have the same number of right-side up cards.

How would you do it?

Comment: An unrelated question, but why are there 53 cards rather than the standard 52?

Comment: :) We have a "joker" card!

Comment: @SaurabhRaje Just one joker, and not the standard two?

Comment: Joke Answer: Rip each card in two and place each half in opposite piles.

Comment: Alright, I dont know, just their question...can we please try to solve it instead of nitpicking?

Comment: A better phrase for "upside card" is "right side up card"

Comment: Dear @SaurabhRaje : It is not nitpicking: it's possible that the number of cards plays some sort of role. It might not matter, but for those of us who don't know the answer offhand we need to be sure you're clear.

Comment: I think "jesterII" may feel left out in your deck of only 53 cards.

Comment: See also [Puzzling.SE]!

Comment: I am (or at least once was) quite capable of detecting a card's orientation by feel alone.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a classic question.

Split the cards into two piles. The first pile has 18 cards, the second pile has the remaining 35 cards. Say that there are $n$ upside down cards in the first pile, and therefore $18-n$ upside-down cards in the second pile.

Now turn over all the cards in the first pile.

Comment: then what? I am still left with some upside down ones?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje It sounds like you haven't computed how many cards remain upside down in both piles at the end of this process.

Comment: Oh sorry, I got it now, thanks! I misinterpreted the question, sorry.

Answer (score 9):

This is an old puzzle, basically you take any set of 18 cards and turn them over. It should be the duplicate of some other question here.

Comment: I don't understand, how will it make all the cards face up?

Comment: I think this is equivalent to what Chris is saying, although Chris wrote a little more.

Comment: The task is to have two piles, each with same number of upside cards. You don't have to make them all face up. Suppose the pile of 18 you picked initially had x cards. Then the other pile had 18-x cards. After flipping over these 18 cards, the x that were face up are now face down while the other 18-x in this pile are now face up.

Comment: rscwieb yes, and his explanation is very clear. I would not have bothered to answer if he had answered before me.

Comment: @Wonder Is that a duplicate or not?

Comment: Oh sorry, I got it now, thanks! I misinterpreted the question, sorry.

Comment: user I could not find another instance of this question. Though unlikely, it is possible that this is the first time it has been posted here and hence is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Wonder Yes, it is the same answer (+1) - I saw that another answer appeared just as I was finishing mine, but since I'd already written it I hit 'post' anyway.

Comment: Chris it is not like either of us had to think about a solution, I think it is good that you hit 'post' as your answer was more detailed.